# duplex connection. Errors when I get disconnected client. C# WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

But I have issue related to callback which is implemented in client side. When client hit disconnect button, it works well, but in case, client crashed for some resaons as disconnecting network, computer shutdown, etc. After that, service doesn't work correctly. It seems service get error too.

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IChatCallback), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IChat
{
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = true)]
    bool Connect(Client client);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Say(Message msg);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Whisper(Message msg, Client receiver);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OperSelectClient(Client oper, string client, bool connect, bool isdisconnect);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void IsWriting(Client client);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsTerminating = true)]
    void Disconnect(Client client);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OperatorsUpdate();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void RefreshClientsAndOperators(Client client);
}

public interface IChatCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void RefreshClients(List<Client> clients);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Receive(Message msg);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ReceiveWhisper(Message msg, Client receiver);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ClientSelect(Client oper, string client);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void IsWritingCallback(Client client);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void UserJoin(Client client);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void UserLeave(Client client);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class ChatService : IChat
{
    Dictionary<Client, IChatCallback> clients = new Dictionary<Client, IChatCallback>();

    List<Client> clientList = new List<Client>();

    public IChatCallback CurrentCallback
    {
        get
        {
            return OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IChatCallback>();
        }
    }

    object syncObj = new object();

    public bool Connect(Client client)
    {
        if (SearchClientsByName(client.Name) && !clients.ContainsValue(CurrentCallback))
        {
            OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted += new EventHandler(delegate { Disconnect(client); });
            OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closed += new EventHandler(delegate { Disconnect(client); });

            lock (syncObj)
            {
                clients.Add(client, CurrentCallback);
                clientList.Add(client);

                foreach (Client key in clients.Keys)
                {
                    IChatCallback callback = clients[key];
                    try
                    {
                        callback.RefreshClients(clientList);
                        callback.UserJoin(client);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        clients.Remove(key);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
}}
```

Comment: What specific errors are you getting?

Comment: There are many. I recorded the video. Take a look please. http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cleI1kBcg